# Rounding prices in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I found following function to round up the price in `WordPress`:

---

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_excluding_tax', 'round_price_product', 10, 1 );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_including_tax', 'round_price_product', 10, 1 );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_tax_round', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);

function round_price_product( $price ){

    // Return rounded price

    return ceil( $price ); 
}
```

---

I have following two issues:

1. The overall total in the cart is not displaying the rounded prices.
2. The above mentioned code applies not for products with variations.

Looking forward to your help! Thanks.

Regards

Comment: Actually, WooCommerce supports rounding natively if you set the number of decimals to 0 in the General Settings area.

Comment: Well ... that was easier than I though! :D Thank you!!!

Comment: It's definitely needed when dealing with clients that do VAT as well as USA sales :D

Comment: Another problem occured. If I use the general setting the VAT amount will not be displayed properly in the checkout. That would be an legal issue. Can anyone help?

Comment: You should be showing prices with VAT, and then in checkout it will show the VAT breakouts.